# how to apply css style in a dynamic list of data using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsp, servlets

I have a list of comments from the database and displaying It to a JSP page for a specific post. In that comment list, I want to add edit and delete options only for the logged users. if the logged user did the comment on that post he will see the edit and delete option the comment he did. for that, I write the below code.

```
           <%

                for (PostComment comment : pcList) {
            %>
            <% User userInfo = usrOp.getUserInfoById(comment.getUid());%>
            <div class="card my-2">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 id="commentUser"><%= userInfo.getFirstName()%> <%= userInfo.getLastName()%></h5>
                    <p class="card-text"><%= comment.getComment()%></p>

                    <a id="actionEdit" class="mx-1 text-warning d-none">Edit</a>
                    <a id="actionDelete" href="#" class="mx-1 text-danger d-none">Delete</a>
                </div>                  
            </div>
            <%
                }
            %>
```

initially, I hide the edit and delete button. To show that edit and delete button logged user I tried in two ways.

**1st way:** I created a  method in DAO class and finding out, the user did comment on that post or not. if it returns **true** value I trying to change the CSS style using javascript. for this method javascript code below.

```
$.ajax({
                url: "CheckUserCommentServlet",
                data: {pid: pstid, uid: usrid},
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    console.log(data);
                    let actionEdit = document.querySelector("#actionEdit");
                    let actionDelete = document.getElementById('actionDelete');
                    if(data.trim() === 'true' ){
                        actionEdit.classList.remove('d-none');
                        actionDelete.classList.remove('d-none');
                    }
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                }
            });
```

**2nd way:** in this method I scan the list using for loop and tried to find out the name from the comment. if that name is equal to the logged user name then trying to change the CSS style for edit and delete action. for this method javascript code below:

```
            let actionEdit = document.querySelector("#actionEdit");
            let actionDelete = document.getElementById('actionDelete');

            let loggedUser = document.getElementById('loggedUserName');
            console.log(loggedUser.textContent);

            let commentuser = document.querySelectorAll('#commentUser');

            commentuser.forEach(e=>{
                console.log(e.textContent);
                if(e.textContent.trim() == loggedUser.textContent.trim()){
                    console.log("you did the comment");
                    actionEdit.classList.remove('d-none');
                }
            });
```

both codes are working only for top comments. it not checking that this comment did by the logged user or not. check the screenshot.[image]

if I did a mistake in this code help me to find out. or if you have a new way to solve it, also can suggest to me.

Comment: `id` attribute values have to be unique. Only the first occurance of an id value can be used. Elements that occur multiple times in your document should be labeled with  the `class` attribute.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier if I use class then it stays hidden as default for both

Comment: You can have ids, they just have to be unique.

Comment: In you JSP template loop over each comment, like you already do, and check if the id of the comment user equals the id of the logged in user. Then based on that add the buttons or not. But don't give the buttons the same `id` attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution here we don't need to write a single line of javascript code. just use if statement. just those below lines of code.

```
   <% 
          if (comment.getUid() == user.getId()) {%>
             <a href="#" class="mx-1 text-warning">Edit</a>
             <a href="#" class="mx-1 text-danger">Delete</a>
   <%}%>
```